# im making a calculator and facing some unknown issues

Tags: javascript, calculator

So I decided to make a calculator for practice sake, and now I'm facing the issue in which console doesn't say any errors, it shows digits on screen, but it doesn't calculate them at all, just adds these values 1 by 1. Here's the code:

```js
let buffer = '0';
let runningTotal = 0;
let previousOperator;


const screen = document.querySelector('.screen');
const all_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.calc_btns .calc_btn');

function buttonClick(value){
    if(isNaN(value)){
        handleButtonClick(value);
    }
    else{
        handleNumber(value);
    }
    updateScreen();
}

function handleButtonClick(symbol){
    switch(symbol){
        case 'A':
            clearBuffer();
            break;
        case '=':
            if(previousOperator == null){
                return;
            }
            mathOperator(parseFloat(buffer));
            buffer = runningTotal.toString();
            runningTotal = 0;
            break;
        case '%':
        case '-':
        case '*':
        case '÷':
        case '×':
            handleMath(symbol);
            break;
        default:
            handleNumber(symbol);
            break;
    }
    updateScreen();
}

function init(){
    for(let i = 0; i < all_buttons.length; i++){
        let button = all_buttons[i];
        button.addEventListener('click', function (){
            handleButtonClick(this.textContent);
            console.log('button clicked');
        })
    }
}
init();

function handleMath(symbol){

    if(buffer == '0'){
        return;
    }

    const intBuffer = parseFloat(buffer);

    if(runningTotal == 0){
        runningTotal = intBuffer;
    }
    else{
        handleButtonClick(intBuffer);
    }
    mathOperator(symbol);
    buffer = '0';
}
function mathOperator(intBuffer){
    if(previousOperator == '+'){
        runningTotal += intBuffer;
    }
    else if(previousOperator == '-'){
        runningTotal -= intBuffer;
    }
    else if(previousOperator == '%'){
        runningTotal %= intBuffer;
    }
    else if(previousOperator == '÷'){
        runningTotal /= intBuffer;
    }
    else if(previousOperator == '×'){
        runningTotal *= intBuffer;
    }
}

function handleNumber(numberString){
    if(buffer == '0'){
        buffer = numberString;
    }
    else{
        buffer += numberString;
    }
}

function clearBuffer(){
    buffer = '0';
    runningTotal = 0;
    previousOperator = undefined;
}

function updateScreen(){
    screen.textContent = buffer;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 50% auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 360px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 20px black;
}

.calc_btn {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(71, 69, 69);
  color: white;
  border-color: rgb(71, 69, 69);
  display: inline;
}

.calc_btn:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.calc_btn:last-child {
  background-color: orange;
}

.calc_btn:last-child:hover {
  background-color: rgb(235, 179, 76);
}

.screen {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 45px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.calc_btn_row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 5% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="screen">
    0
  </section>

  <section class="calc_btns">
    <div class="calc_btn_row">
      <button class="calc_btn">
            A
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            /-
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            %
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            ÷
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="calc_btn_row">
      <button class="calc_btn">
            7
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            8
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            9
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            ×
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="calc_btn_row">
      <button class="calc_btn">
            4
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            5
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            6
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            -
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="calc_btn_row">
      <button class="calc_btn">
            1
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            2
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            3
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            +
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="calc_btn_row">
      <button id="num0" class="calc_btn">
            0
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            ,
          </button>
      <button class="calc_btn">
            =
          </button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I also have an updated [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fbr_7tb8oxI0ayNvG6HM2vy2CckL29wA/view?usp=drive_link).

Comment: You didn’t mention what’s wrong.

Comment: ^ Just provided the issue, and i also posted video

Comment: we cannot see how you are calling the buttonclick function, most probably that method/function is not being called at all.

Comment: If you provide the HTML and CSS then we can actually run your code

Comment: Provided HTML and CSS

Comment: First of all search for all buttos as `const all_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.calc_btns .calc_btn')` and then  add default statement in `switch` as `default: 
        buffer = symbol;` and then do as per the button clicked

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that in your event listener you call directly

```js
handleButtonClick(button.textContent);
```

So here button.textContent is only referenced once. So the value wont change.
You could eventually refactor like this to get a fresh value each time

```js
button.addEventListener('click',function () {
    handleButtonClick(this.textContent);
})
```

Comment: i tried making it this way, although the issue still remains :(

Comment: Have you tried to log the values ? Some debug could give you a hint.

Comment: You replaced the arrow function syntax by function keyword ?

Comment: yes i replaced ^

Answer (score 0):

When you do `button.textContent`, that will include any whitespace. Try `button.textContent.trim()`.

Also handleNumber is never called.

Comment: Nope, didn't help :(

Comment: Added a comment about handelNumber.